# sql query show an error when executed with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

the problem is in the following query

```
$query1 = "SELECT SUM(qyt) FROM vip_allotment_details
           where allotment_id = ( SELECT id from vip_allotment
                                  where date_from >= '2017-10-1' AND
                                  date_to <= '2017-10-31')  ";
```

when i put on date_to the value more than 2017-10-15 it get the following error

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in /home/saudican/public_html/hotel/pages/r_booking_status.php on line 133

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/saudican/public_html/hotel/pages/r_booking_status.php on line 136
```

i can't figure out where is the problem in the query ...

Comment: Perhaps subquery is returning multiple rows. Try `allotment_id IN (...)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if returns more one rows use `IN`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(qyt) 
FROM 
   vip_allotment_details
WHERE 
   allotment_id IN ( 
                      SELECT 
                         id 
                      FROM 
                         vip_allotment
                      WHERE 
                         date_from >= '2017-10-1' 
                      AND
                         date_to <= '2017-10-31'
                     )
```

Comment: thanks man , if i want to show a field from table vip_allotment in php like this <?php echo $row['date_from'] ?> how can i do it from this previous query

Comment: use the variable like: $ date from = $ row ['date_from']; use next: echo ($ date_from);